# Stripe - integrating with Cordova - loading app without net connection

Tags: cordova, stripe-payments

I have a cordova app. I have integrated Stripe with it. 
It works great.
However, when there is no net connection when the app is being launched - the app does not load - and I get the white screen. The log says -

```
 Failed to instantiate module angular-stripe due to:
Stripe must be available as window.Stripe
```

How do I enable my app to be loaded w/Stripe - even when no active internet. May be defer loading Stripe?

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load the stripe library when you need it.

```js
let stripe = document.createElement('script');
stripe.src = 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js';
stripe.onload = function () {
  // What do to do when the library is loaded
};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stripe);
```